# is there a way to make a get request with token and data with both axios and fetch?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, request, fetch

I have learnt that http get requests not meant to accept data as part of what it is sending, and I equally tried this with fetch and axios multiple times trying to perform a get request with body (i.e data) and token, it didn't work

```
await axios.get(
    'https://dev.app.payslice.com/api/account_info', 
    {bank_code: bank?.code, account_number}, 
    {headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`},
}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

this is what is in the docs, but despite this, it was returning unauthorized in the network tab, but after trying to remove the data, and trying the request again it showed authorized but data not passed, (i.e some fields were required).

Any comments would be appreciated

Comment: The short story is no. You should take a look at their API and see if there's an alternative way to do this, or perhaps contact support to see what alternatives they have. If that's a dead end, you'll need a server and a client that supports this (many dont, but some do)